# Angularjs code not updating

Tags: angularjs, caching, production-environment, nodemon, angularjs-digest

I have been facing an issue for quite a long time. I am trying to update my Angularjs code on the server in the production environment but it's not working. My code is running properly on localhost i.e in development environment but when I run the same code on the server it's not publishing the updated code. Even `console.log()` is not working in production environment. As I am new to Angularjs so I followed many links and have tried solutions like

```
$templateCache.removeall(), 
localStorage.clear(),
$scope.$apply()
```

I have also cleaned cache on my server. But still, I am facing the same issue.

HTML file :

```
<supplier-customers-chart supplier-id="{{supplierId}}" direction-of-
sorting="-1" sort-by="filteredShipmentCount" per-page-results="5">
</supplier-customers-chart>
```

Directive Template :

```
<div  class="text-center" ng-show="isloading">
<img src="/img/loading.gif" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="Loading..">
</div>
<div class="chart" id="supplierCustomersChart" ng-hide="isloading"></div>
```

Directive :

```
var customersDataPromiseObject = suppliersService.getCustomersData(data);
        scope.isloading=true;
        customersDataPromiseObject.then(function(result){
          scope.isloading=false;
          var dataArray=[];
          var tempData={};
          var customersData=result.docs;
          for (var i = 0; i < customersData.length ; i++) {
            tempData={};
            if(customersData[i].buyerName.length>50){
              tempData.buyersName = customersData[i].buyerName.slice(0,50).concat(' ... ')
            }
            else{
              tempData.buyerName = customersData[i].buyerName;
            }
            console.log(customersData[i].filteredShipmentCount);
            tempData.filteredShipmentCount = customersData[i].filteredShipmentCount;  //previously I was doing tempData.shipmentCount = customersData[i].shipmentCount;
            console.log(tempData);
            dataArray.push(tempData); // used for AmCharts
          }
```

Previously I was binding with `shipment count` but now I want to bind with `filtered shipment count`

I am using angular - 1.3.20

Yeoman - 2.0.0

Npm - 3.10.10

Node - 6.9.3

Linux Server - 14.04

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Very likely caching in the browser have you looked into configuring the web server to use etags or to set appropriate expires headers?  Every time the app runs the template cache is remade and the local storage isn't used unless you use it explicitly, don't call scope.apply arbitrarily it's only used when you are picking up an async event outside of angular directives/services and are updating the model

Comment: In chrome network panel disable cache then reload the page to see if it is the browser caching the page.

Comment: I have disabled cache in chrome browser but still not working.

Comment: Check the response on the request to see if the updated text is there based on what you posted to the server... something strange going on here

Comment: Are you using apache or nginx for the web server or just static serving pages through node/express?

Comment: I have changed the code in controller and directive but they are not reflected on the server in the production environment and working fine with the localhost. Even console is not working in controller and directive when running on the server.

Comment: Yes I am using apache web server

Comment: Are you seeing the correct response in the response tab on the right after you select the network request in the network requests view?  If not the server is sending the old file/text which is likely because of caching.  Disable cache checkbox and refresh on the page should get around that but can be fixed on the server config too.

Comment: Yes, the service is bringing correct data which I need to bind with the view. Previously I was binding the view with the different variable from the response and now I am binding with other variable but its showing binding of previous only.

Comment: ah so this is just for data requests and you see the correct data in the response but set that on a scope property and don't see it update in the view? definitely not enough information in the question to guess all of that.  The way you wrote "doesn't update published code" sounds like all the static files are old not like you are just having a problem with data binding.

Comment: Anyhow post more of your code around what you're actually doing and or a working example on https://next.plnkr.co or jsfiddle or codepen

Comment: I have edited my question to provide the snippet of my code but this is just part of the problem. Even when I do any change in my controller(even the `console`) it's not working.

Comment: You never answered about seeing the updated code in the response you might have both issues caching on the browser and/or some sort of caching happening on the server as well as issues with how you are trying to get the view updated.  Will take a look at the code for a few here.

Comment: This also doesn't appear to be an angular directive https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive more context with working code will help a lot since not enough information is given here can't really properly debug.  Can try putting your code together here to show the issue with some fake data source (can use $timeout to simulate async things in place of $http) https://next.plnkr.co/edit/tpl:ZxnXqp  You need to post more images of the network requests/responses and what you see vs what you expect as is not enough info to answer what's wrong here.

Comment: Hello Sir, I  have edited the plunker and here's the link https://next.plnkr.co/edit/Ui5qpTEtK4mxZqMr this is how the result should be displayed. But previously I have binded with shipment count instead of filtered shipment count so its showing
SOL GROUP 28,921
THE SOL GROUP 821
SOLEADO S A 4

Comment: Sorry for the slow response.  So with the example plnkr can you describe what you expect vs what's happening, not sure exactly what to look for here still.

Comment: Sir, actually my problem is when I run the application in nodemon development env it works fine, but when I run the same in nodemon production it's not working. In production mode even if I add a console or I try to add a bug from my side so that it show error but none of the changes are reflecting in client side. My server side API's and HTML file are working properly and updating the code. The problem is with angular js file. None of the changes are reflected when I run the application in production mode.